# jquery fileupload does not allow to select files with different extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

How can I make sure that no files are uploaded to my server if they have different extensions, how can I do it with jquery fileupload so that, for example, it can not be selected: pdf, tif at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plug into the change event of fileupload to check on the number of types in the input:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    change: function (e, data) {
        var fileTypes = []; // Array for file types
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {

            var thisExtension = file.name.split('.').pop(); // Get the extension

            if (fileTypes.indexOf(thisExtension) == -1){ // We have a new type
              if (fileTypes.length > 0){
                // Handle invalidation however works best for you
                alert('TWO DIFFERENT FILE TYPES!');
                // Maybe clear the input if you want to be aggressive?
                $("#fileupload").find(".files").empty();

              } else {
                // It's okay, this is the first type
                fileTypes.push(thisExtension);
              }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But this assumes your users are benign and not trying to trick the UI by renaming file extensions. If you want to be 100% sure, you'd want to verify the file server side.

Comment: If it works, please mark the question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
      var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
      if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>2){
       alert("You can only upload a maximum of 2 files");
      }
  });
});​
```

But you need to replace the property "length" for "values" and evaluate the extension.